# Does chgrp -p exist?

Tags: chgrp

Does any version of the chgrp command have a -p option? If so, what does the -p option do?
I am aware of the -P option.

Example usage:

```
chgrp -p folder group
```

where folder is a folder and group a group.

Comment: Could you give us some context here please? Do you have any reason to think such an option exists? Have you seen it used? It sounds like you're asking about a random option here.

Comment: you do "man chgrp" in the terminal. then you search for the -p option. and read what it says. in case that fails can ask here. in that case it would be good to include what the man says and how it fails to address the issue.

Comment: You give a example of the usage of `chgrp -p` but you say nothing more about this and crucially leave out where you have seen this option and what the context for it was there.

Comment: I have seen the option used in a preparation exam for a linux certification. The question is assigning the owning group of a directory to be the owning group of files created in the directory. The two answers given are
chmod 2775 folder
and
chgrp -p group folder.
I didn't find the option in the man pages. So i suspected it could have existed and is deprecated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The `chgrp` from GNU coreutils does not have a `-p` option:

```
# chgrp --help
Usage: chgrp [OPTION]... GROUP FILE...
  or:  chgrp [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...
Change the group of each FILE to GROUP.
With --reference, change the group of each FILE to that of RFILE.

  -c, --changes          like verbose but report only when a change is made
  -f, --silent, --quiet  suppress most error messages
  -v, --verbose          output a diagnostic for every file processed
      --dereference      affect the referent of each symbolic link (this is
                         the default), rather than the symbolic link itself
  -h, --no-dereference   affect symbolic links instead of any referenced file
                         (useful only on systems that can change the
                         ownership of a symlink)
      --no-preserve-root  do not treat '/' specially (the default)
      --preserve-root    fail to operate recursively on '/'
      --reference=RFILE  use RFILE's group rather than specifying a
                         GROUP value
  -R, --recursive        operate on files and directories recursively

The following options modify how a hierarchy is traversed when the -R
option is also specified.  If more than one is specified, only the final
one takes effect.

  -H                     if a command line argument is a symbolic link
                         to a directory, traverse it
  -L                     traverse every symbolic link to a directory
                         encountered
  -P                     do not traverse any symbolic links (default)

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

Examples:
  chgrp staff /u      Change the group of /u to "staff".
  chgrp -hR staff /u  Change the group of /u and subfiles to "staff".

GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/chgrp>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) chgrp invocation'
```

Also:

```
# chgrp -p 
chgrp: invalid option -- 'p'
Try 'chgrp --help' for more information.
```